# Difference of total US Minor Penal Penalties in Low Income Communities vs Higher Income Communities

Tags: data-request

I am doing a personal research project (not an assignment, just something I am passionate about) to share with my Criminology professor. I am trying to find data on whether there is a correlation between community income (as well as race demographics) and amount of punishments for violating minor Penal Codes (ones that often go overlooked).

My theory is that a difference in wealth affects the amount of punishments levied by law enforcement. Off the top of my head I am looking for things as small and simple as Excessive Noise violations (like loud music when it's late), car modifications, and even strictness on whether you should come to a full and complete stop at a stop sign or slow down but just roll through it.

I believe there is an inequality in leniency from law enforcements. If someone in a high income community, I assume it it is likely they'll just give them a polite warning, but the officer would be more prone to issuing a fee if it was in a low income neighborhood. I have spent hours combing the internet for data, but I'm barely finding anything. I am totally willing to accept that I am wrong, but I want to make sure I've exhausted every option I have. Either there isn't definitive data or I just don't know where to look. I am fairly proficient with data analysis using python, SQL, and Tableau, so I really just need the data. IF anyone knows where to look or has even found data sets containing any applicable data I would seriously appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: Just for the USA (as stated in the title), or also elsewhere (your question does not specify any country)?

Comment: Just specifically for the United States is my focus for this